# Since latest android app update I can't scroll the feed sideways

Tags: bug, android-app, android-app-feed

This only happens with the top few feed items (new since refresh maybe, or actually, maybe feed items before the update are OK, ones after aren't) but when I drag right to left to scroll between questions as soon as i get half way it snaps back. Sometimes I can get it to scroll and when I can scrolling back (left to right) works fine.

I'm on a stock Nexus 5.

P.s. On the plus side the app has some really nice ui improvements.

Comment: Hmm, no idea what's changed but it appears to be working again now.

Comment: It seems to be when at the top of the feed, scrolling down a bit before trying to scroll sideways appears to fix it. I think it's probably related to the new refresh (as you suggested).

Comment: Hmm, I think I can reproduce it. If I'm very careful to only scroll horizontally it works, the second I go even slightly off of the title text as i'm dragging it snaps back. I'm sure this behaviour has been introduced recently.

Comment: Still an issue - any plan to resolve?

Comment: Another update after more testing/frustration; it seems like it's the pull-down-to-refresh that's causing an issue. Dragging to the side, then up slightly is fine, I can keep dragging sideways, but when I drag sideways and slightly down it snaps back and suddenly I'm pulling down to refresh. I'm not an android Dev so not sure how to fix it, seems like once one drag action is started that should prevent others from taking over.

Comment: Linking to the official response from the app developer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247616/cant-horizontal-scroll-widgets-on-main-screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be fixed now, at least on my OnePlus One, with version 1.0.56

Comment: Yup, fixed on my Nexus 5 too.